# how to unwind in moongose after populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have two schemas, Mails and Users, as defined here:

```
var MailsSchema = new Schema({
    from   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'UsersSchema' }],
    to   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'UsersSchema' }],
    date    : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    subject : { type: String, default: '' },
    message : { type: String, default: '' },
    isRead  : { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    username    : String,
    pass : String,
    firstName : String,
    lastName  : String,
    age :   Number
});
```

I want to get list of mail that send to specific user, populate the username in 'from' field,

I tried to do it that way:

```
mails.find({ to: id }).populate('from', 'username').exec(function (err, docs)...
```

The problem is:
I'm getting an array in 'from' field, I want to get only the username.

I.e. instead of getting this result:

```
[{"_id":"53fa2902da480e4c0d315fcd","__v":0,"isRead":false,"message":"SABABA","subject":"MA KORE","date":"2014-08-24T18:03:46.428Z","to":["53f9dbe164b1375c1c5b997a"],"from":[{"_id":"53f9dbe164b1375c1c5b997a","username":"adaroh"}]}]
```

I want to get that result:

```
[{"_id":"53fa2902da480e4c0d315fcd","__v":0,"isRead":false,"message":"SABABA","subject":"MA KORE","date":"2014-08-24T18:03:46.428Z","to":["53f9dbe164b1375c1c5b997a"],"from":"adaroh"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how populate works. You can modify the docs yourself to filter out the extra id. In your `exec`, for each doc that gets populated you can look at the `from` array and do

```
doc.from[i] = doc.from[i].username
```